# Visual Studio: How to start a new line, properly indented, in XAML editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I notice that in the XAML editor window Visual Studio will not properly indent a new line if Ctrl-Shift-Enter is pressed from the middle of the line, but rather the cursor appears at the beginning of the new line. How can I have VS properly indent new lines created with Ctrl-Shift-Enter in the middle of a line?

Thanks.

Comment: If I press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the middle of the line, the cursor on my new line will be indented where it should be as if I pressed Enter at the end of the line.  Do you mean to ask how to make the cursor on the new line to be at the same spot on the line where you pressed Enter?

Comment: @brianestey: I now see that the problem is only in the XAML editor. I will clarify the question. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it out with a XAML file and you are correct about the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, brianestey. I filed a bug, you might want to add that you can reproduce the issue as well: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/714471/newlines-from-ctrl-shift-enter-not-indented-in-xaml-editor

Comment: Upvoted your issue.  Good luck getting it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bug in Visual Studio:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/714471/newlines-from-ctrl-shift-enter-not-indented-in-xaml-editor